# Use FontAwesome with Gumby Framework

Tags: css, icons, css-frameworks, gumby-framework

Is there a way to use the FontAwesome icons in the Gumby Framework like in Twitter BootStrap ?

Answer (score 1):

I've came across this problem and what i did was to place this code in my css:

```
.useFontAwesome [class^="icon-"], .useFontAwesome [class*=" icon-"]{
    font-family: fontawesome !important;
}
```

Then whereever you want to use font-awesome icons, you can just attached that class to the wrapping element. If you want, you can add that class to your body tag in order to always have the font-awesome library at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using RoR?
I got it working there. 
You need to change the path where your fonts are located in the variables partial. change it to "/assets", this might work.

Answer (score 0):

I am using them with the Gumby Framework.

The fonts are in the fonts/icons folder.

The `.scss` files are in my var/icons folder.

Then in the `gumby.scss` file add `@import "var/icons/font-awesome";`.

Don't forget to set the `$fa-font-path` in the `_variables.scss` file!